# Wired headset support on Android using USB-C

Tags: headset, usb-c

I just recently lost my OnePlus Nord 2CE which had all my must-have features, dedicated dual SIM slots, SD card support, and a 3.5mm jack.

Now there are very few phones which have these 3 features, so I have accepted that the SD card can go, but as I use an [EPOS wired headset](https://www.eposaudio.com/en/in/enterprise/support/knowledge-base/wired-headsets/sc-100-series/sc-165) which I find really important for long calls, I am wondering if I was to buy a phone with only USB-C, how I could use my wired headset or if there are USB-C versions that work.

I already own iFi Audio GO and Meizu HiFi Audio USB audio adapters for driving proper HiFi headphones. Will these support mic input?

This USB-C [Logitech headset](https://www.logitech.com/en-us/products/headsets/zone-750-wired-usb.981-001103.html) says "Functionality for mobile devices with USB-C depends on the device."

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If it's a recent phone, it should work fine.  The functionality referred to in the Logitech handsets is controlling the app on your phone.  At worst, you may not be able to pause or start the music/video player from the headset.